# SAS- Using Macro to output results as excel

Tags: excel, sas, output

I used following code to export my results as excel files. However, each time, the results are output in the type of file. I have to change their type as excel manually. I tried put `.xls` after `&from.&&memname&i`, but SAS cannot recognise this format. I assume that the possible reason is `.x`, but I don't how to solve this problem.

```
%macro tradetime(sourcelib=,from=,going=,dir=);
proc sql noprint;  /*read datasets in a library*/
  create table mytables as
  select *
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = &sourcelib
  order by memname ;

  select count(memname) 
  into:obs 
  from mytables;

  %let obs=&obs.;

  select memname
  into : memname1-:memname&obs.
  from mytables;
quit;

  %do i=1 %to &obs.;

  ods tagsets.excelxp file= "&Dir\&&memname&i" /*output the results to target file*/
  style=XLsansPrinter;
  ods listing close;
  ods results off;
  proc univariate data= &from.&&memname&i;
  var  time_l_ ;  
  run;
  quit;

  ods tagsets.excelxp close;
  ods listing ;
  ods results on;
%end;
%mend;

%tradetime(sourcelib='AXP',from=AXP.,going=AXP.,dir=D:\Data\description);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an issue from the macro variable terminator.  If you try:

```
&Dir\&&memname&i.xls
```

That will not work.  The dot is the macro variable terminator, and in fact in your case you need more than one because you're using the two `&` - so `&[i].` is one macro variable, and then next you have `&[memname&i.].` as the second one (the first `&` disappears).  So you would need:

```
&Dir\&&memname&i...xls
```

to create the .xls extension.

Note that `tagsets.excelxp` does *not* create native excel files.  It creates xml files that are readable by excel; so excel will give you a little trouble if you put `.xls` on them (in some cases it will open, in some it will refuse to, depending on your settings and version of excel).  It would be preferable to use `ods excel` if you support `.xlsx` files and have SAS 9.4 TS1M1 or later.